# CMake Regex to convert lower case to upper case

Tags: regex, cmake

Hi i'm trying to convert a string of lowercase letters to uppercase using regex in a cmake file.

The command i'm using is:
string(REGEX REPLACE *match replace output input*)

Does anyone know how to specify that each lower case letter be replaced with its uppercase counterpart using cmake's regex facility?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do that with a CMake regular expression. If you just want to convert a string to uppercase you can use the [TOUPPER string function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#toupper):

```
string(TOUPPER <string1> <output variable>)
```

Example to convert the contents of a variable to uppercase:

```
string(TOUPPER ${VARNAME} VARNAME)
```

Comment: it turns out that that is precisely what I want to do, thanks!